# Conditions for a solvable group to have a non-trivial center

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, characters, solvable-groups

I am working on a problem in character theory where I try to bound the derived length of a solvable group using information about its characters. In my specific case, it will be extremely helpful for me if I knew that the center was non-trivial. Here is what I know about the group:

- $G$ is solvable.
- the derived subgroup $G'$ is a $p$-group.
- $G''$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup in G.
- $G$ has a faithful irreducible character.

Of course, a lot of information can be deduced from the above. But in particular, I want to know if $G$ has a non-trivial center. This may not be deduced from the above information, but maybe if some additional condition is satisfied?

Comment: Any finite group with a unique minimal normal subgroup must have a faithful irreducible character, so your final condition is redundant.

Comment: Your group has derived length $3,$ so I am curious to know how this fits with the context you state for the question ( in other words, how would it help to have a non-trivial center)?

Comment: I am trying to prover that my group is supersolvable. Because it has a faithful irreducible character the center is cyclic and then so is G''. This (I think) will help me trying to find a normal series in which every quotient is cyclic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are such groups with trivial centre. One such (possibly the smallest) is a group $G$ of order $448$ with the shape $2^{3+3}:7$. It has derived group $G'$ of order $64$, and $G''$ has order $8$ and is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

This is $\tt{SmallGroup}(448,179)$ in the databases in GAP and Magma. You can compute its character table, and it has two faithful irreducible characters of degree $14$.

*Edit*: In fact $\tt{SmallGroup}(108,17)$ with structure $3^{1+2}:4$ is  a smaller example.